# Discussion of new tag dual-drive-dual-boot

Tags: discussion

An increasing number of questions are appearing where the problem is a dual drive installation of Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on a different drive.

The solutions to dual-drive, dual-boot problems are specific to it and distinct from dual-boot, single-drive problems.

There are  > 14,000 questions tagged *dual-boot*. By using a tag specifically for this, and using it in lieu of the tag 'dual-boot', I hope we can segregate these issues, to lead to quicker resolution.

This question posted at the specific request of Kulfy.

Comment: There is one already https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-drive-dual-boot but it has no questions

Comment: @MarkKirby There were 8 questions tagged as such. All were tagged in a span of 24 hours. I removed the tag and added [tag:dual-boot] instead since according to its excerpt, [tag:dual-boot] also applies to the installations in different drives.

Comment: I would say this still falls under 'dual boot' tags - and doesn't yet need its own tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would add my voice for single tag dual-boot for these reasons:

- Dual boot on separate drives is easier and has more forward solutions. The case is a subset of dual-boot category.
- It is not wise going into that level of sub categories, as Ask Ubuntu has already wide spectrum of support topics. Currently, many tags need to be merged or become synonyms instead.
- A side note about `dual-drive-dual-boot`: it is a long text string.

There is no correct answer for this. Even if keeping it seems wrong, it is not worth the effort opening the door to re-tag almost 15K question.